# Scipy stats.skew -- IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy, outofrangeexception

I am getting a wierd error.... this doesn't happen if I use np.random.random instead of np.random.randint

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy.stats as stats
>>> rdata = np.random.randint(5000)
>>> skew = stats.skew(rdata)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 989, in skew
    n = a.shape[axis]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: `rdata` is a scalar, not a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at the docstrings for [`numpy.random.randint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) and [`numpy.random.random`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html).  `numpy.random.randint(5000)` returns a *single* random integer between 0 and 4999 (inclusive).  `numpy.random.random(5000)` returns an array of 5000 samples from the uniform distibution on 0 <= x < 1.